# Drupal: I've deleted a nodequeue and now I get the following errors

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I've deleted a nodequeue and now i get this warnings on every drupal page:

```
warning: array_fill() [function.array-fill]: Number of elements must be positive in /mnt/hgfs/Sites/carlos/includes/database.inc on line 253.
warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in /mnt/hgfs/Sites/carlos/includes/database.inc on line 253.
user warning: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1 query: SELECT qid, use_parents FROM smartqueue WHERE qid IN () in /mnt/hgfs/Sites/carlos/sites/all/modules/nodequeue/smartqueue.module on line 158.
```

How can I fix this ?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have any nodeques that you need I would try uninstalling the nodeque module, and then re-enabling it, which should reinstall it.